# Salesforce Sites Calendar Not displaying

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have recently started playing around with sites and created a basic page.

```
<apex:page controller="newController">
```

```
    <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock title="Welcome {!$User.FirstName}"></apex:pageBlock>


    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit">

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Travel Details" >

           <apex:inputField value="{!Booking.StartDateTime__c}"></apex:inputField>

            <apex:inputText value="{!Booking.EndDateTime__c}"></apex:inputText>

            <apex:inputField value="{!Booking.StartLocation__c}"></apex:inputField>

            <apex:inputField value="{!Booking.EndLocation__c}"></apex:inputField> 

     </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:form>
```

These are the two fields that I display - one problem though, when a user clicks on the field the calendar fails to popup, they are just acting as a normal textbox.

I have searched on the web and checked user and field level permissions and everything seems to be fine. They are of the datatype datetime.

So does anyone know how I can get this calendar to display?

EDIT: I have made the code remedies suggested but unfortunately had no luck. The inputfield now displays the current date time next to the input box(as in salesforce) but still no calendar popup. I have also built the controller. Possibly a javascript issue?

Any help much appreciated,
Cheers

Comment: You'll also want to wrap your input fields in an apex:form element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, if anyone comes across the same issue you need to activate the site.

Anyway thanks for all the responses.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define a standard controller and wrap your inputfield in a form in order to get the calendar to pop up, the code should look like this

```
<apex:page standardController="Booking__c">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:inputfield value="{!Booking__c.StartDateTime__c}"/>
    <apex:inputfield value="{!Booking__c.EndDateTime__c}"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Also there is a proposal in the works for a dedicated salesforce site sitting in Area-51, the link is http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce. Might be worth your time to give it a vote in-case you need to ask more questions.

Comment: thanks mitch I have made the changes you suggested still no calendar popup. But thanks for the link to area51 - looks excellent

Comment: No reason that your code should not work apart from missing a pageblock end which would have been a copy paste thing. I recreated it in a dev org to show that it works. 

http://mitchqtest-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/test

try looking at your sites profile and make sure that it has the required access to the object, if you are still having problems post your controller code or just try to use a standard controller if its not required.


Edit: Only created startdatetime to save time.

Comment: Cheers mitch - I just needed to activate the site, damn!

Answer (score 0):

Try inputText instead:

> Note: Read-only fields, and fields for certain Salesforce objects with complex automatic behavior such as Event.StartDateTime and Event.EndDateTime, don't render as editable when using <apex:inputField>. Use a different input component such as <apex:inputText> instead.

Source: [apex:inputField (Salesforce.com)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm)

Comment: Hi Tim cheers for the fast response. Unfortunately inputText wont display a calendar so not really ideal.